# multiple value to listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {
        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

it only displaying name on listview... there is an e mail field.. how can i display that too

Answer (score 0):

You are using arraylist of string ... use class model for contact like

```
Class Contact{
   private String name;
   private String email;

   //Constructor, Getter & Setter for Contact

}
```

Then modify your above function like ..

```
Arraylist<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>;
..............................................
while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
   contactList.add(new Contact(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)),res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL))));
    res.moveToNext();
}
```

Now you have name & email for each contact in arraylist ... also you can add more members like address as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **ArrayList** of **String**, use ArrayList of **HashMap** or **your own Model Class**

**Example using HashMap**

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllCotacts() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
    res.moveToFirst();

    while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
      HashMap<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      // add the name
      hMap.put("name", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
      // add the email
      hMap.put("email", res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_EMAIL)));

      // finally add the HashMap to ArrayList
      array_list.add(hMap);
      res.moveToNext();
    }
   // before returning you must close the cursor and database
   res.close();
   db.close();
   return array_list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take array list of object type like ContactData and save data of cursor to object arraylist as below:-

```
public ArrayList<ContactData> getAllCotacts() {
        ArrayList<ContactData> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from contacts", null);
        res.moveToFirst();

        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
ContactData contactData=new ContactData();
contactData.name=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_NAME_COLUMN_NAME))
contactData.email=res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME))        
array_list.add(contactData);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
}
```

Comment: what else i have to do in main class

Comment: call method and get Arraylist of Contact type and set custom adapter